# Node JS Module Not Working . Module Not Found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I Am Trying To Use An npmjs module named systeminformation in the documentation it is given to use it as it is down below but it gives me an error module not found

the code from documentation:

```
const si = require('systeminformation');

 si.cpu()
   .then(data => console.log(data))
   .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

My Code :

```
const si = require('systeminformation');

comp=()=>{
    si.cpu()
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
```

please help me with this I tried reinstalling the node module npm i systeminformation

The NpmJS Module -- https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation

Comment: Can you paste the full error? Also, did you install the package? Are you using yarn or npm?

Comment: yes, sir, I installed the package using npm -- this command -- npm i systeminformation the error was unable to resolve module 'battery' from .... something just like this https://hackernoon.com/images/null-nu42eea.jpg

Comment: @Rastalamm Can you Please Help Me With This

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install crypto:

`Npm install -i crypto`

This will install missing module to your local node modules

Answer (score 0):

Tree remarks to your question:

1. As PDHide suggested to install crypto, should not really solve your problem. This is not a dependency of `systeminformation`, nor is it used anywhere in the code.
2. can you confirm, that installing systeminformation with `npm I systeminformation` does not show any error during the installation? This should be strange if there is an error.
3. be sure to use this package as a backend module within node.js. This module is not intended to be used in front end code (see documentation https://systeminformation.io/). Due to security reasons there is now way to get detailed system information from within a browser. I am pretty sure, that your error message comes while executing this code in a browser or am I wrong?

**tl;dr:** systeminformation package is supposed to be used as a node.js backend/server-side library and will definitely not work within a browser.

Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Did you see the error comment the user has posted ?

Comment: Yes I saw this, ... unable to resolve module 'battery' ... the screenshot was just an example how it looked like, so crypto is just a placeholder here ... it is all about 'battery'. This message sometimes throws, when you try to use systeminformation client side. And this is what I just want to verify.

Comment: The answer was for the screenshot

Comment: Yes, but if you read the comment correctly, it states: "...  the error was unable to resolve module 'battery' from .... something just LIKE ..." and then the screenshot. Right? So the error message is related to 'battery' and not to 'crypto' which would not make any sense. As the creator and maintainer of the systeminformation package, I do know, what is needed to run this package.